# Debug Assertion Failure even when using delete[]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging

I am a beginner at programming and recently wrote this code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void removeAllCharacters(char * , char * );
void printArray(char*);

void deleteArrays(char*,char*);

int main()
{
            char * source,*remove;
            source=new char[18];
            remove=new char[10];

            source="Hello how are you";
            remove="Hi Its me";

            removeAllCharacters(source,remove);
            printArray(source);

            deleteArrays(source,remove);
            system("pause");
            return 0;
}

void removeAllCharacters(char * source, char * remove)
{
            int N1=strlen(source)+1;
            int N2=strlen(remove)+1;

            bool arr[128] = {false};

            for(int i=0;i<N2-1;i++)
            {
                arr[remove[i]]=1;
            }

            char *newSource=new char[N1];

            for(int i=0,j=0;i<N1-1;i++)
            {
                if(arr[source[i]]==0)
                {
                    newSource[j++]=source[i];
                }
            }

            delete  [] source;
            source=newSource;
            newSource=0;
}

void printArray(char* arr)
{
            int N=strlen(arr)+1;

            for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                cout << arr[i];
            }

            cout << endl << endl;
}

void deleteArrays(char* arr1,char*arr2)
{
            delete [] arr1;
            arr1=0;
            delete[]arr2;
            arr2=0;
}
```

I have tried debugging and found only that
    ***The error occurs at delete[] source; in the removeCharacters function.I tried looking for a solution online but i couldn't find it.*** Why is this error occurring? Is the error because I have allocated dynamic memory from main but i am deleting it from the function?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I'm not sure what this is meant to do: `arr[remove[i]]=1`, but it is going to cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `std::string` and your code will work. You are confusing pointers with objects.

Answer (score 5):

The return value of `new[]` is a pointer value.  No matter what happens, when you issue a call to `delete[]` that same exact pointer value must be used.

Obviously this will violate the rule above:

```
    source=new char[18];
    remove=new char[10];

    source="Hello how are you";
    remove="Hi Its me";
```

You're allocating with `new[]`, but replacing the returned value with the value of a string literal.  In other words, that pointer value required to call `delete[]` with is now gone.

Here is an example of what you should have done:

```
    char str1[] = "Hello how are you";
    char str2[] = "Hi Its me";
    source=new char[sizeof(str1)];
    remove=new char[sizeof(str2)];
    strcpy(source, str1);
    strcpy(remove, str2);
```

Note that we created two buffers initialized with the data.  Then we carefully allocate enough storage for the characters (plus the terminating null), instead of counting characters and possibly get something wrong.

Then the `strcpy` function copies the characters over to another buffer.

You also have another error:

```
source=newSource
```

You will see immediately that on return `source` does not have the pointer you just assigned.  The reason is that `source` is a value parameter, thus local to the function -- assigning to it doesn't do anything to the actual value passed to the function, as any assignment just goes up in a puff of smoke when the function returns.

Also, it you're a beginner at C++ programming, you could have started using `std::string` and not char* for string data.  Creating strings using `new[]` is a dinosaur approach in C++.  Use `std::string` instead.  You really should strive to not get into the business of creating strings like this:

```
 char *newSource=new char[N1];
```

This leads to memory leaks, and sometimes spaghetti-like logic in keeping track of the allocated memory so that `delete[]` functions properly.  In addition, most, if not all of these issues mentioned disappear.  Assignments work, no memory leaks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
    source="Hello how are you";
    remove="Hi Its me";
```

This is wrong. The right way is:

```
    strcpy( source, "Hello how are you" );
    strcpy( remove, "Hi Its me" );
```

You cannot "delete" a constant string. You can delete array/memory allocated with "new".

Comment: In case of simple type like "char" there is no difference with delete without []. The brackets are necessary if the elements of array are objects and need explicit call to its destructor.

Comment: @i486--`char* chars = new char[100]; delete chars;` is undefined behavior. In practice it might work, or it might be that only one byte of that 100 byte allocation is freed (depending on how the implementation works). But the rule is, if you use `new[]`, make sure you also use `delete[]`.

Comment: @i486 I'm pretty sure that even in the case of simple, built-in types, you should be using the delete operator that matches the new operator used to allocate storage. If allocated via new[], you should delete via delete[], unless you enjoy undefined behavior.

Comment: If it was allocated with `new[]` then deallocating it with `delete` is WRONG. 100% plain and simple.

Comment: Not fully agree with this. delete[] after new[] is simple rule for students who do not understand everything yet. Practically, delete frees the memory for new char[100] in the same way like delete[]. If the array was ...new my_class[100] then there is big difference - with delete[] will be called the destructor for each object in the array and then will be freed the memory (100 * sizeof(my_class)) bytes and with delete the destructors will NOT be executed - only the memory will be freed...

Comment: ...Learned this when it was necessary to free array of objects and predefined "operator delete" for custom memory allocation/deallocation. Then had to predefine "operator delete[]" as well and saw the effects.

Answer (score -1):

source is passed by value. Calling delete [] source will not have any effect  on source in main function.